# Change y axis text in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset I would like to plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(first=c(40,40,40),second=c(40,80,160),third=c(40,160,640), ID=c("ID1","ID2","ID3")) %>% pivot_longer(cols=-ID)
```

I am using:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=name, y=value, group=ID)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size=4)
```

Currently, I have:
[image]

Is there a way to change the values shown on the y axis:

```
1:40
1:80
1:160
1:320
1:640
```

Basically, I am writing a string for the continues numeric values on y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `breaks=` and `label=` parameters to change your `y-axis` labels

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=value, group=ID)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(40,80,160,320,640), label=function(x) paste0("1:", x))
```

[image]